# Order status "Payment Review" with "processing" or "payment_review" state?

Tags: orders, ee-1.13, order-status

Native Magento EE comes with an order status `Payment Review` with `payment_review` and `payment_review` for the status code and state code, respectively. Let's call this status `A`.

I came across an already-installed extension that installed a separate `Payment Review` order status but with `processing` state code. Call this status `B`. In the order flow, an order goes into `Payment Review` if it fails an initial fraud check or if the invoice somehow fails to capture after it's been authorized.

Is there a reason to be using status `B` over `A`, or vice versa, for any particular reason? I would stick with the native status, `A` and `B` seem redundant.

Comment: Did you make a choice here?

Comment: Yeah, see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I would use the Magento default set-up. I am not saying that it is 100% correct but if you are using the default set-up with EE if you require support from Magento themselves then they should be willing and able to help.

You may find that the module you mentioned was developed for CE and did not have all the statuses and states available so they developed it with the best fit they had.

Comment: Thanks David! I would personally opt for the default payment review status, too, as it puts some restrictions on the order. For example, offhand, I think you can't ship a `payment_review` order. However, I ended up using the payment review status with `processing` state because that's what the client wanted.